# Unexpected behaviour when swapping elements in C list

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, swap

Homework from uni, tl;dr is that we had to create functions: `swap(args)`, `sort(args)`, `max(args)` where sorting is in descending order.

Function that is the core of the problem is `swap`. Array `arr` is of type type `double`, so when I want to swap 2 elements in that list, I should use `double` type, however it produces output:
`9.0 1.0 5.1 3.0 2.0` but when I change `double buffer;` to `int buffer;`, output changes and becomes correct sorted list of`9.0 5.0 3.0 2.0 1.0` and the value `5.1` is rounded down to `5` because of the implicit conversion.

So the question is ***why***?

*Using VS Code with extensions* `C/C++, C/C++ Extension Pack, Code Runner`
Not sure of the compiler but it's latest version of mingw-something.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int max(double t[], int N, int p, int k){
   
    if(p == k){
        return t[p];
    }
    double max;
    int index;
    
    for(int i = p; i <= k; i++){
        if(t[i] > max){
            
            max = t[i];
            index = i;
        }
    }
    return index;
}

void swap(double t[], int N, int p, int k){
    double buffer;
    if(p >= 0 && k <= N-1){
        buffer = t[p];
        t[p] = t[k];
        t[k] = buffer;
    }
}

void sort(double t[], int N){
   
    int indexMax;
    int a = 0;
    int b = N - 1;
    
    do{
        indexMax = max(t, N, a, b);
        swap(t, N, indexMax, a);
        a++;
    }while(a < b);
}

int main()
{         
    printf("\noutput:\n\n");
    double arr[5] = {1, 5.1, 3, 9, 2};
    
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        printf("%.1lf ", arr[i]);
    }printf("\n");
    
    sort(arr, 5);
    
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        printf("%.1lf ", arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n\nkurwa");
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think most of the problems are in your `max` function.

Comment: perhaps O/T, but your `max` function looks needlessly complicated to me. You don't need `p` or `k`, just assume the first index is the max, then loop thru the rest and look for a larger one. You also don't initialize `index`, so under the right (wrong, rather) conditions, you could return garbage.

Comment: `max` is also uninitialized in the `max` function, so who knows what `if(t[i] > max)` will evaluate to. Also recommend changing either the name of the function or the variable, a bit confusing with the same name.

Comment: `return t[p];` in `max` is also nonsense; `t[p]` is a *value* from the array; the function appears to be intended on returning an *index* into that array.

Comment: @yano, our lecturer is - to put it gently - strict, he wanted us to create function from his declaration statement of `maksimum(double t[], int N, int p, int k)` where N is number of elements, p & k self-explanatory. In terms of `int max;`:  I will change it.

Comment: @WhozCraig thanks, changed to `return p;`

Comment: @Janekk very strange. Ironic you say `p` and `k` are self-explanatory. It's been a few hours since I looked at this now, and from your comment I have no idea what `p` and `k` are supposed to be, I'd have to check your code. Whereas `t` is obvious and `N` is reasonably assumed to be the length of `t`. Do what you need to do for this assignment, but you'd be hard-pressed to find a `findMax` function like this that takes 4 arguments like this,, unless the extra args offer some kind of optimization or are necessary for a specific algorithm. Doesn't look like it to me here.

Comment: I think you'll find [this](https://godbolt.org/z/1G45nz3xc) to be a much more common approach to finding the max value/index in an array (assuming no huge data sets, special algorithms, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are problems in the `max` function:

1. When `p == k` it returns an element value (of type `double`) instead of an index.
2. `max` has an uninitialized value in the comparisons until some element happens to be greater than the uninitialized value.
3. If no element value is greater than the uninitialized `max` value, `index` will remain uninitialized and the function will return an uninitialized value.

Here is an improved version of the `max` function:

```
int max(double t[], int N, int p, int k){
   
    if(p >= k){
        return k;
    }
    double max = t[p];
    int index = p;
    
    for(int i = p + 1; i <= k; i++){
        if(t[i] > max){
            max = t[i];
            index = i;
        }
    }
    return index;
}
```

It initializes `max` and `index` to correspond to element `p` and then checks elements `p+1` to `k` to find the element with the greatest value.

The `swap` function is OK, but the sanity checks on the index values are not exhaustive. Here is a better sanity check:

```
    if(p >= 0 && p <= N-1 && k >= 0 && k <= N-1){
```

Comment: My original "better" sanity check for the `swap` function was incorrect as it expected a specific ordering of the `p` and `k` indices when no such order should be expected. Fixed it.

Comment: Based on answers I changed the [code](https://pastebin.com/6Tv7NXP7), however, now the "sorted" list looks exactly like before.

Comment: Fwiw, `max` in this function is a worthless holding place for what amounts to `t[index]`.  The `if` test can be `if(t[i] > t[index])` and the first line within that `if` logical block can be removed entirely.

Comment: @Janekk My original answer had an incorrect sanity test in the `swap` function. Please use the corrected sanity test at the end of the edited answer: `if(p >= 0 && p <= N-1 && k >= 0 && k <= N-1){`.

Comment: @IanAbbott I found the issue, code I linked was old, accidentally winded back to that. Now everything works with [this](https://pastebin.com/r5VLMzXD) code. The issue was about not initializing `buffer` and 1 comparison in the if in `swap` function was copied from `max`, therefore not allowing to swap if p > k.

Comment: @WhozCraig I guess the optimization could go either way, depending on the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

You've got some issues going on that can be addressed by building your program with additional compiler warnings.  Your `swap` function is actually correct, there are instead issues with `max`, lines 7, 9, and 10.

In C, variables inside functions (like `max` and `index`) are **not initialized to 0**. Instead, they get whatever garbage happened to be in them. Since you do not initialize those values (say, to `t[p]` and `p`), `max` is returning incorrect results.